# Tendermint: why GasWanted, GasUsed and Fee appear in in DeliverTx/CheckTx response?

Tags: tendermint

The [ABCI specs](https://github.com/tendermint/abci/blob/master/specification.rst#checktx) declare that results of `DeliverTx` and `CheckTx` contain the following information:

```
...
GasWanted (int64): Amount of gas requested for transaction.
GasUsed (int64): Amount of gas consumed by transaction.
...
Fee (cmn.KI64Pair): Fee paid for the transaction.
```

I'm not sure why these parameters should appear in the response.
How "actionable" are these to the Tendermint Core, if at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feel free to ignore these for now. They are not used by Tendermint core.

Comment: Why not to kill these off all together then?

Comment: We may use them in the future to 1) order txs in the mempool 2) control execution